# How to read all row elements along with the header names?

Tags: text-processing, awk

This is my working test file

```
Name  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
Dir01  val1     val2     val3     val4     
Dir01  val5     val6     val7     val8     
Dir01  val9     val10    val11    val12
```

My desired output is like this

```
for loop over row elements
For Dir01
        Column1 = val1
        Column2 = val2
        Column3 = val3
        Column4 = val4

For Dir02 
        Column1 = val5
        Column2 = val6
        Column3 = val7
        Column4 = val8
For Dir03 
        Column1 = val9
        Column2 = val10
        Column3 = val11
        Column4 = val12
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR==1{split($0,h); next} 
    {print "For " $1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "\t%s = %s\n", h[i], $i}
' file
For Dir01
    Column1 = val1
    Column2 = val2
    Column3 = val3
    Column4 = val4
For Dir01
    Column1 = val5
    Column2 = val6
    Column3 = val7
    Column4 = val8
For Dir01
    Column1 = val9
    Column2 = val10
    Column3 = val11
    Column4 = val12
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a loop over the Dir01 , Dir02, Dir03? So that in each loop it throws column1, column2, column3 and column4 values.

Comment: @MohammedAtta sorry - I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: I want to loop over the row elements (Dir01, Dir02, Dir03). So for the first loop which is Dir01 and it will generate  `Column1 = val1
    Column2 = val2
    Column3 = val3
    Column4 = val4 ` then the next loop which is Dir02 , it will generate  `Column1 = val5
    Column2 = val6
    Column3 = val7
    Column4 = val8 ` and so on ...

Comment: @MohammedAtta: How is that different than what steeldriver has done?